# Disabling wireless (Wi-Fi) network connections to open (unprotected) hotspots

Tags: networking, wireless

This question is related to Ubuntu MATE 16.04, but I would also be interested in knowing this for other "flavors" or previous versions of Ubuntu: is there a way to set up Ubuntu to disable wireless (Wi-Fi) network connections to open Hotspots ("open" in the sense of being unsecured or unencrypted)? The idea here would be to prevent connecting to an open hotspot by mistake.